# Uso del imperfecto con el imperfecto del subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, pretérito-imperfecto, letras-de-canciones, condicional

En la canción de Calle 13 llamada [**Ven y critícame**](https://www.letras.mus.br/calle-13/1384442/) escucho la frase

> ...
> Si yo **quisiera** vender algo **montaba** una tienda
> Prefiero regalarte música, aunque tu no la entiendas
> ...

A mí me parece muy rara esta frase, ya que yo la diría algo así

> ...
> Si yo **quisiera** vender algo **montaría** una tienda
> Prefiero regalarte música, aunque tu no la entiendas
> ...

Claro que la mía no cabe el ritmo de la canción. De todos modos, quiero que me enseñen ¿es común usar el imperfecto así?

¿Tiene alguna relación con que se dice "If I wanted to sell you something, I *would* open up a shop" en inglés ya que el cantante es de Puerto Rico? ¿Quizás es un anglicismo?

¿Quizás no entiendo la frase?

Ayúdenme por favor

Comment: Yo también diría "montaría" -- pero lo he visto así de vez en cuando.

Comment: No es anglicismo. Hay una tendencia en varios idiomas ibéricos para usar el imperfecto del indicativo donde se esperaría el condicional

Comment: Este no es mi fuerte y seguro me corregirán (ojalá) pero para mi hay una sutil diferencia de tiempos. "Montaba" sería presente mientras "montaría" sería en algún tiempo futuro. Existe una tercera opción "si quisiera vender algo habría montado una tienda" que sería el tiempo pasado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas tiene una entrada sobre el uso de los tiempos en oraciones condicionales. Para tu caso, considero relevante el siguiente fragmento de la entrada:

> Si la condición se refiere al presente o al futuro, la prótasis va en pretérito imperfecto o copretérito de subjuntivo y la apódosis en condicional simple o pospretérito [...]. En la lengua coloquial es frecuente hoy el empleo en la oración apódosis del pretérito imperfecto o copretérito de indicativo: *Si me tocara/tocase la lotería, me compraba un coche*

En otras palabras, cuando usamos la prótasis (la parte de la oración que introduce la condición o hipótesis) en copretérito del subjuntivo, como en el ejemplo que usas, **podemos usar el condicional simple o el pretérito imperfecto en la apódosis** (la parte de la oración que introduce la consecuencia o resultado de la prótasis).

`Si yo quisiera vender algo, montaba una tienda.` Pretérito imperfecto del indicativo.

`Si yo quisiera vender algo, montaría una tienda.` Postpretérito del indicativo.

**En resumen, ambos usos del condicional son reconocidos por la RAE.**

Comment: Excelente. No estaba yo tan perdido cuando hice mi comentario antes. +1